# TimeManager on PyQGIS: InvalidTimeLayerError: ValueError('min() arg is an empty sequence',)

Tags: pyqgis, timemanager

I am running a map showing multi-temporal data using PyQGIS and the Time Manager plugin.

I believe that these lines in the code may be a problem.

```
settings = layer_settings.LayerSettings()
settings.layer = earthquakesLayer
settings.startTimeAttribute = "DATE_AND_TIME"
settings.endTimeAttribute = "DATE_AND_TIME"
timeLayer = timevectorlayer.TimeVectorLayer(settings,iface=iface)
```

The last line of the code is giving the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/Aaron/.qgis2/python/plugins\timemanager\timevectorlayer.py", line 100, in __init__
InvalidTimeLayerError: ValueError('min() arg is an empty sequence',)
```

Is there anything wrong with the arguments I have put in the Time Manager?

Here is the whole code I am trying to run.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import*
from timemanager import*
#set background of map to a certain colour
iface.mapCanvas().setCanvasColor(QColor(196,229,248))
iface.mapCanvas().refresh

countries = "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\pygis\world_boundaries.json"
earthquakes = "C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\pygis\Earthquakes.geojson"
basemap = QgsVectorLayer(countries, "World", "ogr")

#colour the basemap to a light grey colour
gray = {'color':'220,221,222'}
mapSym = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple(gray)
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2(mapSym)
basemap.setRendererV2(renderer)

earthquakesLayer = QgsVectorLayer(earthquakes, "Earthquakes", "ogr")
#QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(earthquakesLayer)
earthquakesLayer.setLayerTransparency(30)

magnitude = (("Light",4.5,4.7,"253,255,22","2"),("Moderate",4.7,5.0,"253,190,22","5"),("Strong",5.0,5.4,"253,122,22","7.5"),("Major",5.4,6.2,"253,99,22","9.75"),("Great",6.2,7.2,"253,0,22","12"))

ranges = []
for label, lower, upper, color, size in magnitude:
    props={}
    props["color"] = color
    props["size"] = size
    props["outline_width"] = '0'
    props["outline_color"] = "0,0,0,0"
    sym = QgsMarkerSymbolV2.createSimple(props)
    rng = QgsRendererRangeV2(lower, upper, sym, label)
    ranges.append(rng)

field = "mag"
renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2(field, ranges)
earthquakesLayer.setRendererV2(renderer)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([earthquakesLayer,basemap])


settings = layer_settings.LayerSettings()
settings.layer = earthquakesLayer
settings.startTimeAttribute = "DATE_AND_TIME"
settings.endTimeAttribute = "DATE_AND_TIME"
timeLayer = timevectorlayer.TimeVectorLayer(settings,iface=iface)
try:
    ctrl = Qgis.utils.plugins['timemanager'].getController()
except:
    ctrl = qgis.utils.plugins['TimeManager'].getController()
tlm = ctrl.getTimeLayerManager()
tlm.registerTimeLayer(timeLayer)
tlm.setTimeFrameType('months')
ctrl.setLoopAnimation(True)
start = time_util.str_to_datetime(timeLayer.getMinMaxValues()[0])
end = time_util.str_to_datetime(timeLayer.getMinMaxValues()[1])
tlm.setCurrentTimePosition(start)
ctrl.setAnimationFrameLength(1000)
ctrl.toggleAnimation()
ctrl.toggleAnimation()
```